Does anyone know why I am receiving the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'?
I know the problem has something to do with the nested WinOrlose() method within the PlayGame() method, however not sure where to go from here.
Random random = new Random();

// ...  (irrelevant code removed)

void PlayGame() //This methods plays the actual game
{
    var play = true;

    while (play) 
    {
        int target = random.Next(1, 6); //random number between 1 and 5 
        int roll = random.Next(1, 7); // result of a six sided roll

        Console.WriteLine($"Roll a number greater than {target} to win!");
        Console.WriteLine($"You rolled a {roll}");
        Console.WriteLine(WinOrLose(roll, target)); 
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlay again? (Y/N)");

        play = ShouldPlay();
    }
}

// ...  (irrelevant code removed)

string WinOrLose(int dice, int goal)
{
    //determine whether player has won or lost
    if (dice > goal)
    {
        return Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, You won!");
    }
    else
    {
        return Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You have lost!");
    }
}


Received these error messages when trying to run the program:
(49,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'
(53,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'


In your return Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You have lost!"); statement you call a another function, and Console.Writeline doesn't return anything, so you return void instead of a string. Change it to return "Sorry, You have lost!";

Console.WriteLine does not return a value, so trying to return it as a sting will not work. Perhaps you want to simply return the string so you can print it elsewhere.

In your own words, where the code says return Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, You won!");, exactly what do you think this should mean, step by step? What value do you think should get returned, and why? (Did you try to read the documentation for Console.WriteLine, in order to understand what will be returned?)

Writeline returns nothing with this signature
public static void WriteLine ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0
But your method expects one
string WinOrLose(int dice, int goal)
Perhaps you meant to return the strings instead?
return "Congratulations, You won!";

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that Console.WriteLine returns void, and you are trying to return its result as a string from the WinOrLose method. To fix this, you should construct the message inside WinOrLose and return it as a string, then print the result in the PlayGame method.
 static string WinOrLose(int dice, int goal)
    {
        // Determine whether player has won or lost
        if (dice > goal)
        {
            return "Congratulations, You won!";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Sorry, You have lost!";
        }
    }


WinOrLose Method: Instead of calling Console.WriteLine inside
WinOrLose, construct the win/loss message and return it as a string.
PlayGame Method: Print the result of WinOrLose using
Console.WriteLine.

